# "Unable to establish connection on channel" error when trying to log in

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

Login auth code:

```
Future LogInUserwithEmailandPwd(String email, String pwd) async{

    try{
     User user = (await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: pwd)).user!;

    if(user!=null){
      return true;
    }

    }
    on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
      return e.message;
    }

  }
```

My login() func:

```
login() async {
    if(FormKey.currentState!.validate()){
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      await authService.LogInUserwithEmailandPwd(userEmail, userPwd).then((value) async{
        if(value == true){

        QuerySnapshot snapshot =  await DatabaseService(uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).gettingUserData(userEmail);
        String successfull = "Success";
        ShowSnackBar(context, Colors.green, successfull);
        await HelperFunc.saveUserLoggedInStatus(true);
        await HelperFunc.saveUserEmailSF(userEmail);
        await HelperFunc.saveUserNameSF(snapshot.docs[0]['username']);
        NextScreen(context, ThemePicker());

        }
        else{
          ShowSnackBar(context, Colors.black, value);
          setState(() {
            _isLoading = false;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

I trying to learn firebase and doing a chat app, register has similar code and working fine but when i trying to log in it gives "Unable to establish connection on channel." I already tried old question's answers but they didnt worked on my code.